# "lein deps" not working in cygwin. (window OS)

Tags: clojure, cygwin, leiningen

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: repositories-for does not exits.**
This is error while issuing command **lein deps** in cygwin.

Comment: Please post the project.clj file that you're running "lein deps" against. Also, it helps if you copy & paste the exact error instead of trying to type it over.

Comment: @JoostDiepenmaat **(defproject hello "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1"]])**

Answer (score 0):

If you access internet via a proxy make sure you have configured it in cygwin (using export http_proxy="...") and then check that you can access maven repositories with maven.
I think leiningen uses maven behind the scenes.